# I cannot import three.js correctly

Tags: javascript, import, three.js

I wanted to share the work of my first explorations with three.js with a co-worker. Locally everything looked correct, but
when I tried to upload my project to GH Pages I got this error constantly:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

I tried updating the import links in my script.js file, but I can't seem to fix it. This is how I currently have the links.

```
import * as THREE from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js'
import { OrbitControls } from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js'
import * as dat from 'dat.gui'
```

and I got the same error but applied to 'dat.gui'.

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "dat.gui". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

[Here is the repository](https://github.com/bachiloglu/tests-GL/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: GitHub pages doesn’t deploy the page in the same way you do locally. `import "three";` is only valid in certain environments e.g. NPM, but notably _not_ in a Web environment. See [the “Install from CDN or static hosting” part](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation). Your `script.js` is not for the Web, but for Node.js. `import './style.css'` is not how you include CSS in the Web.

Comment: Thanks! @SebastianSimon
I already updated the library imports and deleted the import line from styles.css but I still don't see the sphere. How should I import the css file?

Comment: _“How should I import the css file?”_ — [Normally](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#including_a_stylesheet).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre]
(this means, your _code must be in the question itself, as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/4642212)_),
including all _errors_. See [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/4642212) — in short: no.

Comment: Try importing your files in HTML, rather than in the JavaScript